Coq dictionary implementations supporting custom key domain that are easy to prove equivalence?
I need to implement a dictionary type in Coq, whose keys need to be from an inductive type defined by myself, and I need to make it easy to prove equivalence between dictionaries. What are some good options for this?
For example, suppose that k !-> v ; d takes a dictionary d and returns a new dictionary with key k updated to have a value v. I want to be able to quickly and easily prove that k1 !-> v; k1 !-> v' ; d is the same as k1 !-> v; d, and that k1 !-> v; k2 !-> v' ; d is the same as k2 !-> v'; k1 !-> v ; d. In other words, updating the same key multiple times is same as only doing the last update, and that updating different keys can be swapped in order.
If it helps, the specific definition I use for the keys is an inductive data type:
Inductive t : Type :=
| a
| b
| c : nat -> t.


stdpp provides such a type. https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/iris/stdpp

dictionaries are often called finite map.
